# Start Java program with a named PID

Tags: java, solaris, startup

I want to start my java program with a named PID (process id) on my solaris box.
While starting whatever PID is generated for my program, I want it to prepend a string so that later on I can identify this specific program and shut it down.

e.g. if PID generated is 1234 I want to create it as EventListener_PID_1234

Comment: The PID is a number not a String and you can't change it. If you want to find the PID, use `jps -lvm`

Comment: PIDs are set by the OS, Java has no way to control it either.

Comment: thanks for the comment, what i want to achive is to mark my process with something specific so that later on i can identify that process out of many other java processes running on the same box to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

you can search through the tasklist.exe to find your program name and then get the PID of it then you can kill it easily here an example to find all process related to chrome browser

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO code application logic here
try {


    String processrow;

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir")+"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");

    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String[] process;

    while ((processrow = input.readLine()) != null) {

        //System.out.println(processrow); to display all tasklist.exe processes table

        process = processrow.split("\\s+");

        if(process[0].equalsIgnoreCase("chrome.exe")) // index 0 hold the program name 
        {
        System.out.println(process[1]); // index 1 hold the program PID assign by theOS 

        }


    }
    input.close();

    // your process killing code gose here
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: I dont want to run another java program just to kill my specific process. There should be some unix command using which i should be able to know the PID of my just started java pragram and save that somewhere, so that later on i can receover that pid and kill it.